# Java .dat file to Python pickle

Tags: java, python, caching, serialization, pickle

I have some cache files that I stored them in **.dat** file in java. These are **HashMap** data structure:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new 
FileOutputStream(cachePath));
oos.writeObject(common_value_Cache);
oos.close();
```

Now using my python program I want to open these files and read them in the same **dictionary** data structure:

```
withopen('/cache.dat', 'rb') as handle:
b = pickle.load(handle)
```

Is there anyway I can do it?
I got lots of error like: ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument

How could I load .dat files in python?

Answer (score 2):

you could try [javaobj-py3](https://pypi.org/project/javaobj-py3/)

java code to generate a cache.json file encoding a HashMap structure

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SaveHashMap{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        HashMap<String,String> obj=new HashMap<String,String>();
        obj.put("foo","bar");
        obj.put("lorem","ipsum");
        obj.put("hello","world");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("cache.dat"));
        oos.writeObject(obj);
        oos.close();
    }
}
```

then, after executing the code above and installing the package with pip3 install javaobj-py3

```
>>> import javaobj
>>> with open("cache.dat","rb") as f:
...     b=javaobj.loads(f.read())
... 
>>> print(b)
{'hello': 'world', 'lorem': 'ipsum', 'foo': 'bar'}
```